# Downloading the Source code of a Webpage

Tags: java, android

I am trying to download the Source code of a web page .
But the problem is the whole code is not being showing up only a small part is downloading every time .

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask < String , Void , String >
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String content ="";
            URL url ;
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            try {

                url = new URL (params[0]);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                int data = isr.read();
                while(data!=-1)
                {
                    char c = (char) data;
                    content += c;
                    data = isr.read();
                }

                Log.i("The Code is ",content);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.getStackTrace();
            }
            return content;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String result =" ";
        DownloadTask DT = new DownloadTask();
        try {

            result = DT.execute("https://www.google.co.in").get();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.getStackTrace();
        }
        Log.i("The Code is ",result);

    }
}
```

Comment: In general, things aren't that easy. Beyond that read [mcve] carefully.

Comment: Reading character by character and using string concatenation to add the new character is about the slowest solution possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's important to close the StreamReader. Might not be a problem, but it's a good practice.

```
              while(data!=-1)
                {
                    char c = (char) data;
                    content += c;
                    data = isr.read();
                }
              isr.close();
            is.close();
```

I think your first page is downloaded fine, but when you try to load it again and again you might face problem. As I said this might not be a fix, but it's important. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Does your log show complete web page it's downloading? I see no problem with your code. You might be missing something. And also as @Henry suggested it's better you use BufferReader, it increases program efficiency.